# how to display current open line and hide previous open lines

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

This is a simple script that draws daily open line. But it also draws the previpus daily open lines. How can I hide them and just display the current (active) bar open daily line. Thank you

```
//@version=5

indicator('Daily Open', overlay=true)

daily_open(x) =>

    trigger = na(time('D')) or ta.change(time('D'))
    ta.valuewhen(trigger, open, x)

plot(daily_open(0), 'Daily Open', color.new(color.blue, 0), 1, plot.style_cross)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete the history of a `plot`. You need to use `line`.

Just create a `var line` and update its coordinates when it is a new day.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

var line open_price_line = line.new(na, na, na, na)

is_new_day = timeframe.change("D")

if (is_new_day)
    line.set_xy1(open_price_line, bar_index, open)
    line.set_xy2(open_price_line, bar_index + 1, open)
else
    line.set_x2(open_price_line, bar_index)
```